# Hiding all databases in SSMS that a user does not have access to without making them db_owner

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I am trying to make it so a test user can only see the dbs that he has access to. Currently, the user can only see the one db that he has access to, but he is now the `db_owner` of that database. I don't feel that a test user should be the `db_owner` as this gives him access to everything in the database. From the articles that I found online, this seems to be the only way to make it so the user can only see the single db. When I use `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [user]` he does not see any db within the server, including the db I have given explicit view privileges to. Is there a way to allow him to only view the single db without giving him `db_owner` privileges?

The article I am referencing is [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2995/how-to-hide-sql-server-user-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio/).

Comment: You mean a test *login*, right? Can you please give us a hint about what version of SQL Server and Management Studio you are using?

Comment: @AaronBertrand SSMS 17.4 and SQL Server 2014. I am writing a c# application that will use the user that I created, but I would like to only see the single database that he has access to in SSMS. Does this make more sense?

Comment: I know you have asked about SSMS, but a heads up with the newish Azure Data Studio. Once deny view any database is set, a user can add a connection to ADS with the target database specified and unlike SSMS, ADS will show the database and objects within the database for the user (and only those objects they have permissions on). They will need one connection per database setup, but once inside the any connection there is no restriction (e.g. you can perform cross database queries). Not perfect, but is a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

First of all if you `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [user]` it will not "see" even the database where it's a memeber of `db_owner` role, except for `sysadmin`, only `database owner` will "see" the database owned by it.

`Database owner` is different from just membership in `db_owner` role, it's a login that has `authorization` on that database (`grant authorization on database::myDB to myLogin`), so only one `login` at a time can own the database, and the corresponding `user` has all the permissions in that database and can "see" it in OE even when `VIEW ANY DATABASE` is denied to the corresponding login.

Saying that there is an alternative solution to your problem, it's [SQL Server 2012 Contained Database Feature](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2428/sql-server-2012-contained-database-feature/)

Starting with SQL Server 20012 you can enable `Contained Database Feature` at the instance level and then make your databases `contained`.

This means that there will be a `database`, not `server` to `authenticate` your users, and all these users will "see" only the databases where they were created. They will not "see" nothing at the server level.

If one day you'll need to migrate your databases to another server, you'll not need to transfer server `logins` to another server, your contained database already contains all its users and they are not "orphaned" because they don't have corresponding logins at all.

Comment: A contained user might be an option, but the OP asked about the *databases*, plural, so you'd have the additional management of multiple copies of the same user, their need to connect to each database independently, and their inability to do things like cross-database queries (or look at jobs, logins, linked servers, etc. if they also should have the ability to do any of those things).